# Local Storage not persisting on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am going back and working on a previous project in my bootcamp, because I would like to add it to my personal portfolio. I have an issue with local storage not persisting on refresh. It stores the values and saves them in local storage, on refresh though it will not display the values I stored until I choose to store another value, then it will display all previous values along with the new one I added. Any thoughts?

```
//Save to local storage function
$("#saveButton").on("click", function() {

    savedMovieObj = {
        Title: tmdbMovieData.results[currentMovieIndex].title,
        Release: tmdbMovieData.results[currentMovieIndex].release_date,
        Overview: tmdbMovieData.results[currentMovieIndex].overview,
        Stars: tmdbMovieData.results[currentMovieIndex].vote_average / 2,
        Poster: tmdbMovieData.results[currentMovieIndex].poster_path,
        VideoID: globalVideoId,
    };

    var movieHistArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedMovieObj"));
    if (!movieHistArr) {
        movieHistArr = [];
    }

    var hasMovie = movieHistArr.find(function(movie) {
        return movie.Title === savedMovieObj.Title;
    });

    if (!hasMovie) {
        movieHistArr.push(savedMovieObj);
    }

    localStorage.setItem("savedMovieObj", JSON.stringify(movieHistArr));
    //console.log(movieHistArr);


    $("#myList").empty()
    for (var i = 0; i < movieHistArr.length; i++) {
        var storedMovieEl = $(
            '<li class=  text-slate-400 ">'
        );
        var storedMovie = storedMovieEl
            .text(movieHistArr[i].Title)

        $("#myList").append(storedMovie);
    }
});
```

I have tried using replace as opposed to empty, but did not produce the effect I thought it would.

Comment: You're not showing the part of your code that you're having trouble with - showing the localStorage values on refresh.. .unless I am misunderstanding something